# Rails - Filter by date range

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Attempting to create a filter select to find schedules with coursedates within a given date range:

AdminController:

```
def find_schedules
  if params[:start_date] && params[:end_date]
   start_date = params[:start_date]
   end_date = params[:end_date]
   @schedules = Schedule.find(:all, :conditions => {:coursedate => start_date..end_date})
  redirect_to :action => 'find_results'  
  end
end
```

find_schedules view:

```
<% form_tag(find_schedules_path) do %>
<%= select_date Date.today, :prefix => :start_date %>
<%= select_date Date.today, :prefix => :end_date %>>
<%= submit_tag "Submit", :disable_with => "Submitting..." %>
<% end %>
```

Error:

```
    Processing AdminController#find_schedules (for ...) [POST]
  Parameters: {"start_date"=>{"month"=>"3", "day"=>"23", "year"=>"2011"}, "commit"=>"Submit", "authenticity_token"=>"...", "end_date"=>{"month"=>"2", "day"=>"16", "year"=>"2012"}}

ArgumentError (bad value for range)
```

I always seem to have trouble with date/datetime stuff.  coursedate is a datetime field in the schedules table, if that makes any difference.  I only need to search for dates, not times.  Do I need to transform the data type somehow because of how mysql stores it?  Or... what else am I doing wrong?  Thanks in advance for your help.

Getting much closer after bdon's help, thank you!  Now I'm getting an undefined method error, but I should be able to figure that out:

```
ActionView::TemplateError (undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass) on line #26 of /admin/find_results.html.erb:       
25: <tr class="<%= cycle('odd', 'even') %>">
26: <% @schedules.each do |schedule| %>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're getting this error because the "range" function doesn't support hashes, which are being passed in this case:

```
1.9.3-p0 :008 > {:year => 2012, :month => 11, :day => 1}..{:year => 2012, :month => 12, :day => 1}
ArgumentError: bad value for range
```

Instead you need to make the start and end of the range be DateTime objects:

```
1.9.3-p0 :010 > DateTime.new(2012,11,1)..DateTime.new(2012,12,1)
=> Thu, 01 Nov 2012 00:00:00 +0000..Sat, 01 Dec 2012 00:00:00 +0000
```

So

```
start_params = params[:start_date]
start_date = DateTime.new(start_params["year"].to_i, start_params["month"].to_i, start_params["day"].to_i)
```

Do the same for end_date.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply.  Datetime crud baffles me.  I tried your fix, but received :  ArgumentError (comparison of String with 0 failed)    I also tried: start_date = params[:start_date].values_at(:month, :day, :year)      ...  any thoughts?  Thanks again.  :)

Comment: Editing original response: you'll need to turn each of the params from strings to integers with to_i.

Comment: Getting closer, thanks... getting another error now, but I should be able to work through it.  :)

Comment: ActionView::TemplateError (undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass) on line #26 of /admin/find_results.html.erb:       
26: <% @schedules.each do |schedule| %>

Comment: In your controller action for find_results, you need something like @schedules = Schedule.find(:all, :conditions => ...) . If it doesn't find anything that matches, it'll return an empty array. Since you're getting nil instead of an empty array, you must be doing something else.