# How to add integers from multiple model records? [Rails]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, model, view

I have a model that stores an integer every day. I need to add all these integers up, and then multiply the total by its price, which is stored in a different model and different for each user. In other words, imagine there are three records in the database:

Total Value = (Day1 * Day2 * Day3)*Price

This total value needs to be displayed on the users dashboard, so I don't think it's a number that needs to be stored in a database. How would I go about doing this in Rails?

Thank you!

Comment: Please provide more info: how you fetch Day1, ..., Day3? Do you display `Total value` for one user (on user's dashboard) or for several users (as open statistics for group of users)? (if previous answer is "for several users") how you fetch `Price` for each user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, there are not enough information to help you. But if I understand, you have this schema (Assume that we have model called Entity):

```
date:date
sold:integer
```

So, if if you have such table, the query to calculate all entities should be like this:

```
@entities = Entity.all
@entities.sum(&:sold) * price #=> Price multiplied by total sum of sold.
```

If you need to sum only specified range, you can handle it like here: [Rails - Filter by date range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9317350/rails-filter-by-date-range)